# Why will my CSS not display?

Tags: html, css, web

- css file = `base.css`
- html file = `base.html`
- link = `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/base.css" />`
- css location = `C:\Users\user\S\St\static\base.css`
- html location = `C:\Users\user\S\St\Templates\base.html`

When I run my webpage only the html displays. When I point my browser directly to the css file all I get is the literal words written in the file like so:

```
body{background-color:blue}
```

I have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: What kind of code is that? *Is* that code?

Comment: From what I see the path should be `../static/base.css`. That would be the relative path. For an absolute path, I would have to know the root directory of your web-site.

Comment: what is the language are you using?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas ok ill change it and try

Answer (score 5):

It's because your url is wrong.  If your root is

```
C:\Users\user\S\St\
```

Then your css link should look like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/base.css" />
```

There are lots of resources that have more information about this, like this one:
http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/css/style-html.html